# Nuxt 3 - Image corrupted and size reduced after uploaded into Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload image, which captured on the web, into the Google Cloud Storage. I am succesfully able to upload the image into storage but the size is reduced (original captured image size: ~400kB, when upload: 54B). Plus, when I try to open the uploaded image on a new tab, it just a small pixelated white image that appeared, not the image that I originally captured in the first place.

So, how to properly upload the image into google cloud storage, without its getting corrupted?

Below is the code:

1. page.vue

```
 <template>
    <v-card
        height="80"
        class="rounded-lg mt-2 d-flex justify-space-between"
        color="#7698DB">
        <h3 class="mt-2 ml-2">Group Picture</h3>
        <v-btn
            class="mt-4 mb-4"
            style="margin-right: -70px;"
            rounded="lg"
            height="50"
            prepend-icon="mdi-camera-outline"
            @click="openCamera()"
            >Take Picture</v-btn>
    </v-card>
    <div class="py-4" v-if="openCam">
        <video width="365" height="300" ref="video" autoplay></video>
        <div class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
            <v-btn 
                width="155" 
                @click="closeCamera()"
                color="black"
                class="mr-2"
            >Close</v-btn>
            <v-btn
                width="155" 
                @click="takePhoto"
                color="#f2c849">Take Photo</v-btn>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img v-if="imageUrl" :src="imageUrl" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px;" />
    <button @click="uploadImage">Upload Image</button>

    <img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/sir-dev/image" />
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data: () => ({
        openCam: false,
        imageUrl: null
    }),
    methods: {
        openCamera() {
            this.openCam = true;
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(stream => {
                    this.$refs.video.srcObject = stream;
            });
        },
        closeCamera() {
            this.openCam = false
            this.openCam = false
            const stream = this.$refs.video.srcObject
            const tracks = stream.getTracks()
            tracks.forEach((track) => track.stop())
            this.$refs.video.srcObject = null
        },
        takePhoto() {
            const video = this.$refs.video
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0)
            const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
            console.log(`Image data URL size: ${dataURL.length}`)
            this.imageUrl = dataURL
            this.closeCamera()
        },
        async uploadImage() {
            try {
                const requestBody = {
                    imageDataUrl: this.imageUrl,
                }
                const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
                const response = await axios.post(
                    '/api/toStorage', 
                    requestBody,
                    { headers }
                )
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        },

    },
}
</script>
```

2. /api/toStorage.js

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const requestBody = await readBody(event)
    const imageDataUrl = requestBody

    const storage = new Storage({
        projectId: 'projectName',
    })
    const bucketName = 'sir-dev'
    const fileName = 'image'

    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)
    const file = bucket.file(fileName)

    try {
        const base64String = imageDataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '')
        const buffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64')      
        const blobStream = file.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
              contentType: 'image/png'
            },
            resumable: false,
        })
        blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err)
        })
        blobStream.on('finish', () => {
            console.log(`Image uploaded to ${bucketName}/${fileName}.`)
        })
        blobStream.end(buffer)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error decoding image data: ${error}`)
    }
})
```

I'm using Nuxt 3, Vuetify, Axios, and Google Cloud Storage.

Any helps would means a lot to me. Thanks!